# When and how did Beedle the Bard know the story of the Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

### Beedle the Bard, a wizard who writes fairy tale, is also the author of The Tale of the Three brothers. The three brothers were Antioch, Cadmus, and Ignotus Peverell.

The tales of Beedle the Bard are known, for many, that those stories don't exist and are plainly fairy tales.

**But the Tale of the Three Brothers is real according to the HP DH, *the Elder Wand, The Resurrection Stone, and the real Invisibility Cloak.***

From these events, Beedle seemed to be realistic enough to write such 'tale' that exists.

***By such,*** ***did he actually believe that this story is real or did he believe that it was just a rumor. If he believed that the Master of Death exists, where did he get the information of the Peverell brothers' story of the Deathly Hallows?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### We don't know.

It's repeatedly stated in the book [The Tales of Beedle The Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard) that Beedle's stories are an original creation of the author rather than a retelling of older stories ([pace](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43593/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-word-pace) the Brothers Grimm).

Whether any of these stories, especially the Tale of the Three Brothers, had any inspiration that *predates* Beedle's book isn't known however it's noteworthy that there are **no mentions of alternate versions of his stories other than those that derive directly from his book.**

> **If his stories accurately reflect his opinions, he
> rather liked Muggles, whom he regarded as ignorant rather than
> malevolent; he mistrusted Dark Magic, and he believed that the worst
> excesses of wizardkind sprang from the all-too-human traits of
> cruelty, apathy, or arrogant misapplication of their own talents.** The
> heroes and heroines who triumph in his stories are not those with the
> most powerful magic, but rather those who demonstrate the most
> kindness, common sense, and ingenuity.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Tales of Beedle The Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard) - Foreword by JKR</sup></sub>

and

> A pro-Muggle story showing a Muggle-loving father as superior in magic
> to a Muggle-hating son? It is nothing short of amazing that any copies
> of **the original version of this tale** survived the flames to which they
> were so often consigned.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Tales of Beedle The Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard) - ALBUS DUMBLEDORE
> on “The Wizard and the Hopping Pot”</sup></sub>

and

> “The Warlock’s Hairy Heart,” however, does not appear to have been
> modified or much criticized **in the hundreds of years since it was
> first written;** the story as I eventually read it in the original runes
> was almost exactly that which my mother had told me.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Tales of Beedle The Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard) - ALBUS DUMBLEDORE
> on “The Warlock’s Hairy Heart”</sup></sub>

and

> **Though some six centuries have elapsed since Beedle wrote this tale,**
> and while we have devised innumerable ways of maintaining the illusion
> of our loved ones’ continuing presence
>
> <sub><sup>[The Tales of Beedle The Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard) - ALBUS DUMBLEDORE
> on “Babbitty Rabbitty and Her Cackling Stump”</sup></sub>

and

> The irony is that a curious legend has grown up around this story,
> which precisely contradicts the message **of the original.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Tales of Beedle The Bard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard) - ALBUS DUMBLEDORE
> on “The Tale of the Three Brothers”</sup></sub>

With regard to the final story in the book, given the close similarity between Beedle's story and the artifacts that the Peverell Brother are supposed to have created (some three hundred years before the book was written), it's feasible albeit unlikely, given their substantial age differences, that he'd actually *met* with one of the three brothers. Failing that, he may have simply been told the story by someone with a connection to one of the minor characters.

Comment: That doesn't mean he invented the stories, only that he wrote them down.

Comment: @ibid - There's not really another way to interpret "***his** stories accurately reflect his opinions*" These are his stories, not other people's (with the exception of the "Three Brothers" which we're told is "*legendary*").

Comment: Two people will write down the same story very differently. We can usually determine the views of the writer by which stories he chooses to pass on, how he writes then, which qualities he focuses on, etc.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Indeed, and if this question was about the Grimm Brothers that article would be highly relevant.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - The implication of the foreword by JKR is that he wrote them himself. That he was the author of them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - And I think you're getting too hung up on the comparison betwee Beedle and the Brothers Grimm when no specific connection exists.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I feel like I've had to answer a different question but see edit. These were definitely original stories. JKR says so, as does Dumbledore.

Comment: Good enough for me.

Comment: So, it's still possible that 'maybe' the story of the Peverell Brothers reached Beedle, and he tried to make his own 'version' of the story that was legendary?

Comment: But I don't think that he made a contact with one of the brothers. The brothers were born in 1214. Beedle the Bard was born in 15th Century.

Comment: @BookStriker - Beedle **wrote his book** in the 1400s. Taking into account wizard life-expectancy, it's possible that he was born in the 1280s, met the three brothers in his early teens and wrote his book when he was in his low hundreds

Comment: what is your source? mine is harry potter wikia. Sometimes it confuses me because the results are different from each another. it may be possible, since the brothers could have possibly reached long age before they died, or at least one of them

Comment: @BookStriker - Beedle [*flourished* (fl.)](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Beedle_the_Bard) in the 15th century but we don't know the exact date of publishing of his book, nor do we know his birth-date. The Peverells were definitely alive in 1214 and the eldest [died in the 1290s](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/File:IgnotusPeverellGrave2.jpg). Beedle could, theoretically have written his book in 1401 and been born in the late 1200s. It's not likely, but it's possible.

Comment: While I still disagree with your first quote, your second and third quote provide sufficient proof. +1

Answer (score 4):

In real life, did the Brothers Grimm actually write the fairy tales? No,  they collected them. The Peverall Brothers story seems to have been elevated to the status of legend, with meeting  Death.  I would assume that Beedle also just collected the stories.

Comment: This assumption (with the exception of the story of the Three Brothers, which may be based on reality/an earlier story) is contradicted by JKR's and Dumbledore's writings in the Tales of Beedle the Bard. The majority appear to be original fiction by the author.